# Grails formRemote updating wrong div

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp, grails-3.0

Having a comment within a comment but I'm having trouble in updating via form remote in correct place

I have this code

```
 <div id="comment">
        <g:render template="comment" var="comment" collection="${review.comment}" />
</div>
<g:formRemote class="ui comment form" name="commentForm" 
            url="[controller: 'game', action: 'addComment']" update="comment">
```

The problem is `it's updating correctly in the database. but In the view it is only updating in the top most parent comment and not the correct comment`

**Sample pictures:**
 [image]

**After clicking Add comment button :**

[image]

**After refreshing the page:**

[image]

Don't mind the miss arrangement on the last picture I have a little sorting problem which I'm gonna fix later, the problem is the `formremote` updating the wrong one. The last picture is just to show that the update in the database is correct

edit:

Here is the action and template

```
def addComment(){
    gameService.addComment(params.comment,  params.gameId, params.userId, params.reviewId)
    def comment = gameService.listComment(params.gameId,params.reviewId)
    render(template: 'comment', collection: comment, var: 'comment')
}
```

**template:**

```
 <div class="comment">
<a class="avatar"> <img
    src="${createLink(controller:'user', action:'avatar_image', id:"${comment.user.id}" )}" />
</a>
<div class="content">
    <g:link class="author" controller="user" action="userProfile"
        params="${[userId:"${comment.user.id}"]}">
        ${comment.user.name }
    </g:link>
    <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date"> ${comment.date }
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        ${comment.comment }
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: you should show the controller action, and the template content.

Comment: Rather than loading whole div can't we just load the comment you did after persisting it in database and then open another text area or just make existing text area empty. This will improve performance of your page as well.

Comment: How do I just load one comment?

Comment: have you tried to debug the ajax call with firebug or other inspector ? Try to find all dom elements with that id, and check if the template is correctly generated and sent to the browser

Comment: Sorry im still new to web programming I dont know how to use  those

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your first piece of code already is used multiple times, resulting in more than one div with the id "comment" (I guess that because you have multiple textareas and thus multiple forms in your screenshots, and this would totally explain your problem).

So, if you have multiple div-tags with the same id, the formRemote places the returned html inside the first one.

<sub>Edit: damn, just noticed that this question is quite old :-/</sub>